# How to make a ListView take up space to fill the screen if it only has a small item count

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have a screen that shows an image carousel, rating, and a comments system.

I want the comments to scroll with the page (so the image disappears as I scroll through comments).

Currently, the code looks like:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
                height: 360,
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                autoPlay: false,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                  setState(() {
                    _current = index;
                  });
                }),
            items: List.generate(5, (index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: _current == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.black,
                    width: 4,
                  ),
                ),
                child: FadeInImage(
                  placeholder: AssetImage("assets/images/set-placeholder.png"),
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: List.generate(5, (index) {
              return Container(
                width: 8.0,
                height: 8.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 10.0,
                  horizontal: 2.0,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 10.0,
              horizontal: 20.0,
            ),
            child: StatefulStarRating(
              rating: 4,
            ),
          ),
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: List.generate(2, (index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(child: Text("P")),
                ),
                title: Text(
                    "This is comment ${index + 1} for photo ${_current + 1}"),
              );
            }),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Add a comment",
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                  20.0,
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

When the comments numbers are small, I want the add a comment box to sit at the bottom of the screen. 
If the comments numbers are big enough, I want the add comment box to just sit below them. This means does not have to always be on the screen.

How can I do this? What am I missing?

I have tried using Expanded around the ListView, but this creates a render issue and so won't render.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use SliverAppBar?

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan is that for the top photo you mean?

Comment: Yes, and on scroll it moves the picture up and fades it away so you can go through your list

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan Good idea. Will this then make me able to move the comment box to the bottom (aka fill some blank space if it exists?)

Comment: To push comment box tho the bottom add   Expanded (child:Container())  just above comment widget block. The empty space will be taken by Expanded widget and comment block will be at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can put `Container` for comments to `Scaffold` attribute `bottomSheet`

```
bottomSheet: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
```

Step 2: You can wrap `ListView` with `Flexible`

```
 Flexible(
          child: ListView(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                  height: 360,
                  viewportFraction: 1.0,
                  autoPlay: false,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      _current = index;
                    });
                  }),
              items: List.generate(5, (index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: _current == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.black,
                      width: 4,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: FadeInImage(
                    placeholder:
                        AssetImage("assets/images/set-placeholder.png"),
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: List.generate(5, (index) {
                return Container(
                  width: 8.0,
                  height: 8.0,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0,
                    horizontal: 2.0,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: _current == index
                        ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                        : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 10.0,
                horizontal: 20.0,
              ),
              child: StatefulStarRating(
                rating: 4,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: List.generate(2, (index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      child: Center(child: Text("P")),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                        "This is comment ${index + 1} for photo ${_current + 1}"),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Add a comment",
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              20.0,
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StatefulStarRating extends StatelessWidget {
  int rating;

  StatefulStarRating({this.rating});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //int rating = 0;
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return StarRating(
          onChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              rating = index;
            });
          },
          value: rating,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class StarRating extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(int index) onChanged;
  final int value;
  final IconData filledStar;
  final IconData unfilledStar;
  final double size;
  final Color color;
  final int marginFactor;

  const StarRating({
    Key key,
    @required this.onChanged,
    this.value = 0,
    this.filledStar,
    this.unfilledStar,
    this.color = Colors.orange,
    this.size = 20,
    this.marginFactor = 5,
  })  : assert(value != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: List.generate(5, (index) {
        return RawMaterialButton(
          child: Icon(
            index < value
                ? filledStar ?? Icons.star
                : unfilledStar ?? Icons.star_border,
            color: color,
            size: size,
          ),
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
              width: size - size / marginFactor, height: size),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          onPressed: onChanged != null
              ? () {
                  onChanged(value == index + 1 ? index : index + 1);
                }
              : null,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty much as I wanted. Does make the comment box always fixed at the bottom though.